# Append a link-to from a post response in Ember

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I have a JSON response from an external server that generates a grid of responses. The route they go to is setup in Ember, but I can't figure out how to use the link-to helper in appending the results, causing the application to reload when clicking.

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    switchGenre(genre){
      $.post('https://somewhere.com/search',{'genre':genre},function (data) {
        $('#stations').empty()
        var activeRow = 0;
        $('#stations').append('<div class="row" id="row'+activeRow+'">')
        $.each(data,function(index,station){
          if(index%4==0 && index > 0){
            activeRow++;
            $('#stations').append('<div class="row" id="row'+activeRow+'">')
          }
          $('#row'+activeRow).append('<a href="/station/'+station.id+'"></a>')

        })
      })
    }

  }
});
```

Comment: Instead of manipulating DOM directly through jquery, why don't you write `{{each` block using the response.

Comment: How can i use Handlebars in the JS file though? `{{each data as |station index|}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume, your component name is `my-stations`. Now define `stations` array in init method of the `my-stations.js` file , and iterate in `my-stations.hbs` file. Ask `switchGenre` method to update `stations` array then it will re render your component with latest response.

Comment: if you find it difficult, let me know i will prepare the code `my-station.js` and `my-station.hbs` and update  it in answer

Comment: I got the stations array to update from the switchGenre action, but am unable to get the view to update.

Comment: Check [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/ec4c0a88555e85718c3aa66da81b8191?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs) for basic demonstration.

Comment: For some reason I am getting `TypeError: _this.set is not a function`

Comment: if you do `console.log('_this object',_this);`, then you will come to know what is there in `_this`.  pls update that code in my twiddle or in your question.

Comment: There is one more powerful way of debugging.. just add `debugger;` line. it will stop execution in that line and you can inspect all object and its properties.

Comment: After inspecting `this` it was returning the JSON request rather than an Ember object. I assigned the ember `this` to another temp variable and it worked.